# ajax.responseText to paragraph

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a search form where when someone enters the salary(which is unique in my case), it returns the corresponding values from the database. I am using ajax to do that, i have managed to retrieve the value in input fields. I have an onchange event on my input text which calls in "UpdateCityState"

I would like to show the values inside paragraphs and not input field.

```
<p id='employee_name'></p>
<p id='employee_age'></p>
<p id='safe_code'></p>

<script>
var ajax = getHTTPObject();

function getHTTPObject()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
    //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
}
return xmlhttp;
}

function updateCityState()
{
    if (ajax)
    {
        var employee_salary = document.getElementById("employee_salary").value;

        if(employee_salary)
        {

            var param = "?employee_salary=" + employee_salary;
            var url = "test04.php";

            ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
            ajax.send(null);

        }
    }
}
function handleAjax()                                                                                                                           
{
    if (ajax.readyState == 4)
    {
        var employee_name = document.getElementById('employee_name');
        var employee_age = document.getElementById('employee_age');
        var safe_code = document.getElementById('safe_code');
        if(!!ajax.responseText) {
            var result = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            if(!!result){
                employee_name.value  = (!!result.employee_name) ? result.employee_name : '';
                employee_age.value = (!!result.employee_age) ? result.employee_age : '';
                safe_code.value = (!!result.safe_code) ? result.safe_code : '';
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried replacing  employee_name.value with  employee_name.text but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `value` with `innerHTML` everything should work.